# Prove that Vertex Cover belongs to NP

Tags: algorithms, np, polynomial-time

How to prove that the problem *VERTEX-COVER* belongs to $NP$?

The problem VC is defined as follow:

> INSTANCE: Graph $G = (V,E)$ and an integer $k$
>
> PREDICATE: Is there a subset $V_1 \in V $ s.t $\mid V_1 \mid \leq k $ and $\forall (u,v) \in E $ $u \in V_1  $ or $v \in V_1$ ?

---

**My approach:**

I know that the class $NP$ can be defined as the class of all problems that can be solved using non-deterministic algorithms that runs in polynomial time.

Therefore, i can guess if $\mid V_1 \mid \leq k$ then test for each node in $E$ if $u$ or $v$ belongs to  $V_1$. In this case return $TRUE$, otherwise $FALSE$.

Comment: For which $V_1$ do you guess whether $|V_1| \leq k$?

Comment: For all $V_j$ i think

Comment: There are exponentially many potential $V_1$s. You want a (nondeterministic) polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: So what about using a "Guess  function" that do this task ?

Comment: The question asks you to spell out how this would work.

Comment: The algorithm that i want to design would work as follow: first it "guess" a vertex cover over $2^{\mid V\mid}$ possible covers and then it verify if the guess worked. So the guess has linear time, the algorithm has polynomial time. Right?

Comment: Right, that's the idea. Perhaps you could answer your own question now.